# How do I split the CCK e.g. add node form into a wizard?

Tags: nodes, entities

I would like to split an /node/add form into multiple parts in a wizard format. Ive seen tutorials for doing this with registration but not with node/add. Any tips?

Comment: simple question, straightforward answer no. Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [multistep node form](https://drupal.org/project/msnf)

> For each step you can define which fields should be included in this
>   step. "Fields" includes core-fields like "Title", "Body" or "Authoring
>   information" as well as fields defined by other modules (e.g. Date).